# Filesystem hot reload with React in Docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm

I have a simple React application. I'm developing the React app inside a Docker container. To do a hot reload, I use Docker volume mounts to mount my local filesystem containing the source into the Docker container.

When I start up the Docker container, it works great. When I make a change to one of my source files, my development server automatically restarts. However, when I make a *second* change, the development server no longer detects changes on the filesystem.

Short of setting up Unison or rsync or something like that to sync local fs to my Docker container, does anyone have any other ideas?

(I'm on Mac OS X, and I'm using Docker CE 18.02).

Comment: A bit off-topic but why do you develop your React app inside a Docker container? What are the benefits?

Comment: In short: environmental consistency. With a Docker container, I can guarantee that my dev environment is the same as production, and any other dev who wants to work on the same code will have the exact same env. (I'm running Kubernetes in production). I can insure that, for example, the exact same JVM version is running everywhere. It also simplifies the process of bootstrapping a dev env. You could use something else like Vagrant of course but then you would still have something different in prod.

Comment: But a React app is a JavaScript file. It runs the same way everywhere. Why is the JVM version relevant here?

Comment: In my case, I use a node server. So I want to use the exact same Node version, operating system, configuration, etc.